# Javafx clipboard com error when trying to copy writeable image of scatterplot to cliboard

Tags: image, plot, javafx, clipboard, snapshot

I would like to copy an image of a vbox, the plot within it in particular to the clipboard.
Here is what I'm trying

```
try {
WritableImage snapshot = plotvbox.snapshot(new SnapshotParameters(), null);
Clipboard clipboard = Clipboard.getSystemClipboard();
ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
content.putImage(snapshot); 
clipboard.clear();
clipboard.setContent(content);
} 
catch (Exception e) {}
```

The copy works with no issues, everytime I paste the image, it is correct, but I get the following error:

```
Error:80040064 in GetData(pformatetc In, &sm)
```

Repetitively, Any ideas about if this code is correct or how to stop this error?

Comment: like BrianV I get this error when copying text out of a JavaFX HTMEditor field, and paste it into a Microsoft Word document. The error appears on the ctrl+v ("paste") command

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, I'm getting an error very much like yours:

```
Error:80040064 in GetData(pformatetcIn, &sm)
COM Error:80040064 Invalid FORMATETC structure
Error:80040064 in GetData(pformatetcIn, &sm)
COM Error:80040064 Invalid FORMATETC structure
```

I get this error when copying text out of a JavaFX TextField, and paste it into a Microsoft Word document. The error appears on the "paste" command (i.e. I'm doing it manually - copying text from my app and pasting that text into MS Word).  The paste works fine, i.e. the data shows up, but I get the error above in my NetBeans console window, written to Std Err it seems.

I mention this only because it may help troubleshoot the issue... I haven't figured out the answer yet. I'm a relative newbie here and can't post this as a comment, otherwise I would.

Comment: I have the same error when I try to put an image in the clipboard. More precisely, the error is printed when the image seems to be too big (maybe larger than screen size)